# Unanswerable question led to new question - should I edit or delete the unanswerable one?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question and it received some upvotes, and several comments and a reply. In the course of this I posted several updates to the question, supplying information requested by comments as well as results of my own further investigations.

I am now at a position where I realise that the question I asked is not really answerable, or is too localised, although the comments and replies provided much useful information. But I now know the correct question I *should* have asked to solve my original problem and would like to ask this.

How far is it acceptable to keep clarifying a question with more information, to the point where the question has morphed into something else entirely?

But if I vote to delete the question, then the existing information in it and the comments and replies will be lost, and if I post a new question I will have to repeat much of the original question content.

So should I delete it or fix it?

Comment: Is the "reply" that you mention in your question here an answer? Or just another comment, but one that addressed the core of your problem?

Comment: I suppose looking at it objectively, the reply mostly answers the question but doesn't solve the actual problem. Perhaps I should simply accept the reply, edit down the question so it clearly asks the question that the reply answers (i.e. remove all the irrelevant information), and then post a new question. (That will though leave several odd-looking comments on the question.)

Comment: I'm not asking about the quality of the post but whether the reply was registered on the SO site as an answer or as a comment. Did the user click "Add comment" to create the reply or "Add answer"? It matters because we treat answers differently from comments. But since you say "accept the reply" in your comment, I'm inclined to think it was an answer since there is no formal mechanism for accepting comments.

Comment: Yes, it was a reply, not a comment.

Comment: Editing the question is of course highly indicated, you should however avoid making existing answers completely invalid.  If that's the risk then just ask a new question.  Link to it in your original.

Comment: More importantly, link to the old question from the new one, and explain why the suggested approach fell short in your scenario.